# Create Array of found words in Python

Tags: python, search, text, data-analysis

I have a message of text and a list of terms. I'd like to create an array that shows which terms are found in the message. For instance:

```
message = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
terms = ["quick", "fox", "horse", "Lorem", "Ipsum", "the"]

result = idealMethod(message, terms)
=>   [1,1,0,0,0,1]
```

Because "quick" was the first item in the list of terms and was also in the message a 1 is placed in the first position in the result. Here's another example:

```
message2 = "Every Lorem has a fox"
result2 = idealMethod(message2, terms)
=> [0,1,0,1,0,0]
```

**Update:**
The terms need to be exact matches. For instance if my search term include *sam* I don't want a match for *same*

Comment: Probably want to look at the python NLTK

Comment: Are you using 0s and 1s as booleans, where a 1 simply indicates the term occurred, or are looking for a count? Maybe it would be helpful to add this message as an example: `"The quick fox beat the slow fox in a race"`.

Comment: @Matthew the 0s and 1s represent found and not found. I'll update question to clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
words = set(message.split(" "))
result = [int(word in words) for word in terms]
```

Note that `split()` splits on whitespace by default, so you could leave out the `" "`.

Comment: You can just use `message.split()`

Comment: @jterrace yes, but using `set` removes duplicates and makes the `in` check faster

Comment: no, I'm saying use `set(message.split())` - which by default splits on whitespace

Comment: @jterrace ah, I see; apologies for the misunderstanding. On this, I think it is better to be explicit, but I will add a note

Comment: @jonrsharpe see the result of `'first second    third'.split(' ')`, this is not the same as `split()`

Comment: I disagree - the default splitting will handle tabs, newlines, and even supresses duplicates spaces, e.g. `"hello  world".split(" ")` vs `.split()`

Comment: @m.wasowski that is true; which is better depends on what the OP is doing

Comment: @m.wasowski jonrsharpe was first one in. Thanks all

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension and leverage fact, that `True` is evaluated as `1` in numeric context:

```
words = set(message.split())
result = [int(term in words) for term in terms]
Out[24]: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

*EDIT* changed to look only for whole word matches, after clarification.

Comment: This would struggle if e.g. `"foxglove"` was in the `message`

Comment: @jonrsharpe depending on definition, if term `fox` is in `foxglove` or not... I didn't make any assertions other than what OP explicitly declared. He wanted terms in message, not in words from message.

Comment: I need to find exact matches. This method will find partial matches of text. i.e: term of 'sam' will match 'same' 'sample' and 'besame'

Comment: fixed. Which makes it almost the same as @jonsharpe answer ;)